# Young's inequality with duality bracket

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $R^n$ with smooth boundary $\Gamma$. let $u$ be in $H_0^1(\Omega ) \cap {H^2}(\Omega )$, ${{\partial _\nu }}$ denote the normal derevative. I have the following integarle$$\int\limits_\Gamma  {{\partial _\nu }u.vd\Gamma } $$
I want to apply Young's inequalty $ab \leqslant \frac{{{a^2}}}{{4\varepsilon }} + \varepsilon {b^2}$ to estimate eatch terme alone. 
with $v$ $ \in $ $L^2({{\partial \Omega }})$.
Is that makes sense? thank you.

Comment: You've written the same integral twice, did you really mean that? Restricting $v \in L^2(\Omega)$ to $\partial \Omega$ doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I'm  sorry for the mistakes, I have modified the question. Thank you.

Comment: Still, I don't understand the problem. Applying Young's inequality might make sense or not depending on what you're aiming at.

Comment: The question is: under the above assumptions on $u$, do we have $${\partial _\nu }u \in {L^2}(\Gamma )?$$ ? Thanx.